# Как реализовать заполнение круга цветом от 0 до определённого значения (процесс выделение сектора)?

Tags: html, css

1. Суть процесса - визуализация выделения сектора окружности. 
   Можно представить суть происходящего так: представьте стрелочные часы. Одна из двух стрелок зафиксирована, вторая - двигается. Поначалу стрелки друг на друге - круг белый. По мере удаления одной стрелки от другой пространство между ними окрашивается в красный. Вот именно такую анимация и нужно реализовать.
2. Меня устроит не только пример реализации, но и ссылочка на материал, где можно ознакомиться с материалом на тему.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-draw-a-pie-chart-and-doughnut-chart-using-javascript-and-html5-canvas--cms-27197

Answer (score 3):

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #70b1ff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}

.none {
  background-image: none;
}

.sector-30 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.sector-90 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle none"></div>
<div class="circle sector-30"></div>
<div class="circle sector-90"></div>
```

Comment: Можно ли анимировать данный процесс (linear-gradient ...) ?